# How to add Google's "I'm Feeling Lucky" Search to firefox?

Tags: firefox, google-search

This has been asked before but none of other methods are working now.

Previously we were able to set Address Bar search or Search Bar to I'm Feeling Lucky, but Firefox has put a limit on those ways.

Is there any way now to add Google's `I'm Feeling Lucky` to Firefox's `Search Bar` or `Address Bar`?

> I search a lot and 99% of the times I want the first result, while this might look being lazy for a click, I estimated that it is actually taking hours of my time monthly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The URL for Google's "I'm Feeling Lucky" button is https://google.com/search?btnI=&q=%s (where %s is your search term).

The icon used is http://www.google.com/favicon.ico

Knowing these two, all you need to do is to construct your own [OpenSearch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSearch) XML plugin. Now you can do this manually of course, but there are sites that can do the work for you so why not use those?

One such site is [Ready2Search](http://ready.to/search/en/). I already made the plugin for you. If you want to review or modify it just go [here](http://ready.to/search/en/?sna=GoogleLucky&prf=https%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com%2Fsearch%3FbtnI%3D%26amp%3Bq%3D&des=Google%20%28I%27m%20Feeling%20Lucky%29&img=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&in=ino&ou=ono&mod=pn). To install the plugin in IE, Firefox or Chrome, just click the link that says "OpenSearch plug-in GoogleLucky" (to the right of the 3 browser icons). If you want to view the generated XML, click the "Download the setting of OpenSearch" button.

Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks for being so awesome, I wasn't hoping for any replies at all, but yours fixed my issue in 5 sec :) wish you the best in life.

Comment: You're most welcome. :)

Answer (score 4):

In Firefox, you can use the [keyword search](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Using_keyword_searches) feature.  Create a bookmark like this:

[image: I'm Feeling Lucky Quicklink]

Then in the URL bar, you can type `gl your search query` to be taken to the "I'm Feeling Lucky" results for "your search query".

Comment: what is this feature called? (replacing `%s` with  argument) are there other placeholders available? thank you!

Comment: Apparently it's called "keyword search"; link added in answer.

Comment: i get an forwarding note with this and have to click to be forwarded. how to skip that?

Comment: I've noticed that started happening recently, and I don't know of an easy way (short of a browser plugin) to skip it.  My guess is that they've instituted this as a security measure.  Imagine if a malicious actor arranged for the number one hit for some rare phrase ("horse battery staple badguy"?) to be a compromised site, and then phished users by sending them "obviously safe" google links that silently land them at the compromised page.

Comment: It doesn't look the same any more, but this still works. I had to set browser.urlbar.update2.engineAliasRefresh to true in about:config to get an "Add" button on the search engines. This script skips the redirect notice page https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/390770-workaround-for-google-i-m-feeling-lucky-redirect/code.

Answer (score 2):

Save the following to a file 'googlefeelinglucky.xml' and place it in "%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\XXXXXXXX.default\searchplugins"

```
<SearchPlugin xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/2006/browser/search/">
<ShortName>FeelingLucky</ShortName>
<Description>Google's I'm Feeling Lucky Search</Description>
<InputEncoding>UTF-8</InputEncoding>
<Image height="16" width="16" type="image/x-icon">http://www.google.com/favicon.ico</Image>
<Url type="text/html" method="get" template="https://www.google.com/search?btnI&amp;q={searchTerms}"></Url>
<Url type="application/x-suggestions+json" template="http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?output=toolbar&amp;hl=en&amp;q={searchTerms}&amp;gl=ca"/>
<SearchForm>https://www.google.com/search</SearchForm>
</SearchPlugin>
```

If you don't want to do that, you can just click on the Google (I'm Feeling Lucky) link here:

http://mycroftproject.com/dlstats.html

Creating Mozilla Search Plugins:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Creating_MozSearch_plugins

Answer (score 1):

**Works for firefox (I believe there should be a similar thing for chrome as well)*

Well, if you are really feeling lucky, it mean you must also be feeling ducky. So here's how you use duckduckgo as your on-demand I'm feeling lucky search engine:

**TLDR; I'm feeling LUCKY = I'm feeling DUCKY**

1. Go to duckduckgo.com
2. right click on search box and click `Add a keyword for this seacrh`
3. Name the bookmark `.` to save space on your bookmarks bar.
4. Set the keyword to `d`

Then this is how you search in the browser address bar when you feeling lucky:

`d wikipedia !`

How it works:

`d` : searches on duckduckgo

`!` : takes you to the first search result

Comment: A great answer, I had forgotten about the bangs. Confirmed to work also on `lite.duckduckgo.com`.

Comment: And to add, adding a keyword isn't necessary, you can simply search duckduckgo.com anyway you prefer (including from [the homepage](https://lite.duckduckgo.com/lite/)).

Comment: yeah that's really cool. learned about the ddg lite. I prefer to use it with the keyword because i want google as my default search but still be able to use the ddg bangs from the address bar